# SQL Server 2008 Remote Access

Tags: sql-server-2008, remoting

I've studied other topics, tried various solutions, but cannot gain access to my SQL Server remotely from my PC.

I have not problems with accessing the Server its running on, I'm able to Remote Desktop fine.

Here are the steps  I have taken :-

1. Enabled Remote access to SQL Server
2. Created a SQL Authentication User Account (which Ii can log in with whilst on the server).
3. Enabled Shared Memory & TCP/IP Protocols for the SQL Server Instance.
4. Created a Firewall Rule for TCP Port 1433
5. Created a Firewall Rule for UDP Port 1434
6. Created a Firewall Rule for SQLBrowwer.exe
7. Created a Firewall Rule for SQLservr.exe
8. Ensured SQL Browser & SQL Server are running processes.

SQL Management Studio cant even detect the instance of the SQL Server in listed Database Engines.

I'm at a loss as to what the problem could be?

** UPDATE **

Ive tried turning off my Firewall, the SQL Server in now found in SSMS, but i still cant connect to it?

Answer (score 0):

All your steps are right, I'd do the same. I'm sure everything is fine with your SQL Server.

I guess it's firewall, try to turn it off or run this from command prompt:

```
netsh firewall set portopening protocol = TCP port = 1433 name = SQLPort mode = ENABLE scope = SUBNET profile = CURRENT
```

Also, check if you have antivirus software or something similar and turn it off (on both sides).